# R studio nested display windows task bar font size

Tags: r, fonts, rstudio, font-size, display

How can I change the appearance of each nested windows within R studio?

Please see example below. The font sizes are tiny for source window, note the file names display, difficult to read or see, same as code lines within the window.

While I can modify the overall window's task bar on top through View/Zoom options (font size for File, Edit, etc), I can't seem to figure out how to modify task bars for individual windows such as for source, or console. The fonts are so small with default display resolution setting, even wearing magnifying computer glass doesn't seem to mitigate the problem.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Zooming in with `View > Zoom In` seems to increase the size of all elements, including the file names in the Console Pane.

**Before:**

[image: Before]

**After:**

[image: After]

Comment: Okay, the contents within the window definitely are enlarged. Though the tabs on the frame of the window remained small. So I guess this answered 50% of the question! Thanks.

Comment: Glad to help (50%)! What do you mean by tabs on the frame of the window? On my computer, everything seems to get bigger. Maybe there's a difference between Mac and PC?

Comment: You may be right! It seems that the tabs on each frame also enlarged, though much subtler. I have to check again as it didn't seem to make much different on extended screen in the office... But it definitely worked on my laptop :). The different could also be my PC.